While running JS program showing 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', with node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145 throw err;
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sande\3D Objects\JavaScript-Lesson\lesson08.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v21.7.2



please provide a little code, on which line of code you are getting this error. This error might occur because of path issues.

Upon checking in System variables Node path was pointing to
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
so I changed it to
C:\Program Files\nodejs
And then I restarted the Visual Studo Code or you can reboot your PC too, then it works for me :)


To resolve the error below,
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sande\OneDrive\Desktop\JavaScript-Lesson\lesson01.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v18.20.2

We can just right-click on .JS file and open integrated terminal to run the script:

